# How to test an IntentService with Robolectric?

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric

I'm trying to test the `onHandleIntent()` method of an `IntentService` using `Robolectric`.

I'm starting the service with:

```
Activity activity = new Activity();
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyService.class);
activity.startService(intent);

ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity);
Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedService();
assertNotNull(startedIntent);
```

seems like `startedIntent` is not null, but `onHandleIntent()` doesn't seem to be called.

how should I test it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onHandleIntent` is a protected method so it can't be called directly.

my solution was to extend the service class in my test case, override `onHandleIntent` making it public and calling `super.onHandleIntent(intent)`

then call `onHandleIntent` directly from the test case.

Comment: Hi. I followed your guideline. I didn't have to write the service in my test case, but just included a public method which calls onHandleIntent which also passes my intent.. Rather that having my activity start the service.. I simply instantiate the service class and make the call. I also included a receiver with the intent, and it was successfully received!

Answer (score 14):

Robolectric has a [`ServiceController`](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/robolectric-3.0/robolectric/src/main/java/org/robolectric/util/ServiceController.java) that can go thru service lifecycle just like activity. This controller provides all methods to execute corresponding service callbacks (e.g. `controller.attach().create().startCommand(0, 0).destroy()`).

Theoretically we can expect that [`IntentService.onStartCommand()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java#130) will trigger  `IntentService.onHandleIntent(Intent)`, via its internal `Handler`. However this `Handler` uses a `Looper` which runs on a background thread, and I have no idea how to make this thread advance to next task. A workaround would be to create `TestService` that mimics the same behavior, but triggers `onHandleIntent(Intent)` on main thread (thread used to run tests).

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class MyIntentServiceTest {
    private TestService service;
    private ServiceController<TestService> controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        controller = Robolectric.buildService(TestService.class);
        service = controller.attach().create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RuntimeEnvironment.application, TestService.class);
        // add extras to intent
        controller.withIntent(intent).startCommand(0, 0);
        // assert here
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        controller.destroy();
    }

    public static class TestService extends MyIntentService {
        public boolean enabled = true;

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // same logic as in internal ServiceHandler.handleMessage()
            // but runs on same thread as Service
            onHandleIntent(intent);
            stopSelf(startId);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Alternatively, it's quite straightforward to create a similar controller for IntentService, as follows:

```
public class IntentServiceController<T extends IntentService> extends ServiceController<T> {
    public static <T extends IntentService> IntentServiceController<T> buildIntentService(Class<T> serviceClass) {
        try {
            return new IntentServiceController<>(Robolectric.getShadowsAdapter(), serviceClass);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private IntentServiceController(ShadowsAdapter shadowsAdapter, Class<T> serviceClass) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        super(shadowsAdapter, serviceClass);
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> withIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.withIntent(intent);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> attach() {
        super.attach();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> bind() {
        super.bind();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> create() {
        super.create();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> destroy() {
        super.destroy();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> rebind() {
        super.rebind();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> startCommand(int flags, int startId) {
        super.startCommand(flags, startId);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public IntentServiceController<T> unbind() {
        super.unbind();
        return this;
    }

    public IntentServiceController<T> handleIntent() {
        invokeWhilePaused("onHandleIntent", getIntent());
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `attach()` calls are implicit as of Robolectric 3.4, and [the methods have been marked `private`](http://robolectric.org/migrating/#activitycontrollerattach). Instead, [services are automatically attached when the controller is created](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/android/controller/ServiceController.java#L18).

Answer (score 2):

### Robolectric 3.1+

Create an instance of your service

Call onHandleIntent directly

```
    YourService svc = Robolectric.buildService(YourService.class).get();
    Intent fakeIntent = new Intent();
    fakeIntent.putExtra(YourService.SOME_EXTRA, "debug|fail");

    svc.onHandleIntent(fakeIntent);

    assertThat(something.happened).isEqualTo(true);
```

Note: use `Robolectric.buildService` (not `.buildIntentService`) even if you're testing an IntentService.  `.buildIntentService` is currently not working, as far as I can tell.

Update 2017-05-17:

Issue with `buildIntentService` will be [fixed in future](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3080#issuecomment-301212291)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have approached this the wrong way.
You are testing here:

```
Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedService();
assertNotNull(startedIntent);
```

that `startService()`was called.

You then must assume that Android has implemented their end correctly and that after calling `startService()` the service will indeed be started.

I think that if you want to test the behavior of `onHandleIntent()`, you must just call it directly??

I am not sure exactly... but I think the test you want to write would just be testing the Android framework. You should write two tests.

1) Test that `startService()` is called (as you have in your example).

2) Test the behaviour of `onHandleIntent()` (by calling it directly).

I have very little experience with `Robolectric` but hopefully this is helpful.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    mainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class)
            .create()
            .start()
            .resume()
            .get();
    context = Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
    bt_start = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt_stop = (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

@Test
public void serviceIsOn(){

    bt_start.performClick();
    Intent intent = Robolectric.shadowOf(mainActivity).peekNextStartedService();
    assertEquals(MiService.class.getCanonicalName(),intent.getComponent().getClassName());
}
```

and then I run the test and all is ok

Comment: You are not testing the `onHandleIntent` of the service, as the OP asked. You are testing that the activity calls the service.