# How to test IntentService with Roboelectric - with an error

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, intentservice

I'm having an error message below and looked around but there is a solution for service and tried to get it right.

[How to test an IntentService with Robolectric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025611/how-to-test-an-intentservice-with-robolectric)

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
>   tapme.data.service.AlarmService.(java.lang.String)

Here is the unit test that I implemented -

```
    @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
    public class AlarmServiceUnitTest {

    private AlarmService service;
    private IntentServiceController<AlarmService> controller;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        controller = Robolectric.buildIntentService(AlarmService.class).create();
        service = controller.create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void alarmServiceShouldBeNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(service);
    }
}
```